# How to set a control in parent window based on selection in jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am launching an aspx page within a jquery dialog using

```
var url = "SomePage.aspx";
            $("#divPop").load(url).dialog({
                position: '50px',
                modal: true,
                closeText: '',
                bgiframe: true,
                height: 'auto',
                width: '1000',
                open: function (event, ui) {


                },
                close: function (event, ui) {

                }
            }).dialog("open");
```

Within the popped up aspx on selection< i pick a row in  a jqgrid.

On closing the dialog, I want to be able to set the value for a textbox in the 
calling page using the selection from the dialog. Different pages can 
launch the same aspx using a dialog and I wish to be able to set the value for 
the textbox with different ids in the different pages

Comment: it's important to note that jquery dialogs load in **the same DOM** as they are opened from (unless you stick an iframe in the dialog, which is not recommended).

Comment: I am going to use a hidden field and see if that works. But I am open to other suggestions